# UITabbarController default item content was not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image]I have implemented UITabbarController, which contains 5 items. By default first item in viewcontroller should have been visible, but its not. When I view the second item and get back to first item, only then the first item is visible.

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour. So you'll have to show us a little more: What did you exactly do (storyboarding, plain code) to add the VCs to the TabbarController, etc.

Comment: @Preetha, can you show a picture? or some code here?

Comment: andreas oetijen, aircraf i was attached a snap shot for this example,consider as a 5 items,by default 1 item data will be shown in everytime i opened the application.

Comment: Did you connect them via storyboard or via code?

Comment: @Preetha please add screen shot storyboard or code of tabbarcontroller.